# Fire trigger on insert statement when 0 rows inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Im showing 5 tables from library database

BOOK(book_id, title, total_num, borrowed_num)

BOOK_COPY(copy_id,book_id,status)

READER(reader_id)

BORROWED_BOOKS(reader_id,copy_id)

QUEUE(reader_id, copy_id)

// status represents enum{free, borrowed}

1. INSERT INTO BORROWED_BOOKS(reader_id, copy_id) SELECT somereader_id, copy_id FROM BOOK_COPY WHERE book_id = somebook_id AND status = 'free' LIMIT 1;
2. My question is: How to write a trigger that - when above INSERT returns 0 inserted rows - adds reader to queue table?

Comment: Try  `FOR EACH STATEMENT`, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Seems like something that could work, however my school server has postgresql 11 version... anyway ill try to check it somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: Its the same with Postgres 11.

Comment: @clamp Is it possible to somehow get value of what I put into INSERT? I.E INSER INTO human(name) values('John'). when using FOR EACH ROW it was possible using OLD.name or NEW.name. Is there any workaround when using FOR EACH STATEMENT?

Comment: `NEW` or `OLD` does not make sense in case of many rows processed by the statement. You can add more than one trigger to the same table. Or you can access the changes through `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS temp_table`. (see the link I shared inmy first comment)

Comment: I understand that it doesn't. I only pointed that OLD and NEW is a method of obtaining parameters passed to INSERT() in case of FOR EACH ROW trigger. I need to obtain those parameters in FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger. There is one important difference for me between ROW and STATEMENT - when insert ends up inserting 0 rows 'STATEMENT trigger' will fire when 'ROW rigger' would not. But in STATEMENT i don't know how to get parameter values. (in 'ROW trigger' case i limited num of inserts by LIMIT 1 so beaviour was like per-statement. One corner case when INSERT ends up in 0 that I cannot solve

Comment: @clamp and sorry for such long questions, I don't mind if you ignore. Thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: What would you expect in `NEW` given that the trigger runs once and, say, 10 rows are affected? Why not install a (seperate) row-trigger. Or perhaps edit your question and try to explain what you are trying to achieve. See also [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @clamp Thanks for X-Y problem reference. I edited question. Hope it is in clear way now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228072/discussion-between-clamp-and-pooo-mn).